# Linearising the equation of thin lens with y intercept 0.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, taylor-expansion

## Intro

I have this equation:

$\frac{1}{u} + \frac{1}{v} = \frac{1}{f}$

This is the equation for thins lens derived from the lens maker formula. Refer to the link below for physical background(not needed)

https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/University_Physics/Physics_(Boundless)/24%3A_Geometric_Optics/24.3%3A_Lenses

## Background and question

I have the values of u and v and want to plot a graph of $y(v)$ against $x(u)$ to determine f which is $m(f)$ [f as a function of gradient]. In simpler words my aim is to linearize the equation. However, the y intercept of the linearised form should be 0 to greatly simplify the plot. Note that u and v both vary but f is a constant to be determined.

## My try

I know that the simplest way to get a linear plot is rearrange as follows:

$\frac{1}{v} = -\frac{1}{u} +\frac{1}{f}$ plotting $\frac{1}{v}$ against $-\frac{-1}{u}$

But this is not what I am struggling with.

continuing, I solved for v and got:

$v = \frac{uf}{u-f}$

for very small f, I can use the taylor expansion on $\frac{1}{u-f}$ ignoring the higher order terms and get the simplified form:

$v = -u(1-\frac{u}{f})$

Unfortunately, I can't use this expression to plot a straight line. Using other ways to solve for v doesn't get me the form $y(v) = m(f)x(u)$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A variation of your initial attempt ($1/v=1/f-1/u$ means $1/v$ is a linear function of $1/u$) is to multiply both sides by $u$. This rearranges to $u/v=(1/f)u-1$, so $u/v$ is a linear function of $u$ with $y$-intercept $-1$ and slope $1/f$. (The LHS is a function of both $u$ and $v$, so this doesn't suit your criteria.)